# Carousel (Angular 2)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular2, slider, carousel

Я пытаюсь написать свою собственную карусель на Angular2, но не знаю как это сделать правильно ( т.к. не имею опыта работы с Angular2 ) Скажите пожалуйста где можно найти туториал или гайд по написанию своей карусельки без внедрений каких-либо библиотек)

Answer (score 0):

Нууу, брат (с) :)

Если тебе это поможет, то вот реальное демо: 
https://embed.plnkr.co/VKLszgqJtobyVruBj3Op/

вот - статья для этого демо: https://scotch.io/tutorials/responsive-carousel-component-with-angular-2

а вот тут лежит в меру неплохой курсец по angular2, по хорошему, стоило бы начать с него: https://coursehunters.net/course/angular2udemy

Удачи :)

Comment: Дайте более развёрнутый ответ. Одних ссылок для него недостаточно.